# How do I find the summation of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{2^{x}}$$

This looks like a geometric series but the $x$ is throwing me off. I don't know how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you mean $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}$$

Answer (score 0):

You could show by induction that $$\sum_0^n \frac {x}{2^x} = 2^{-n}(-n+2^{n+1}-2)$$
and then use the limit on that.